# Removing duplicates from a List in Java using iterators

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Im trying to work on an assignment question for my intro java course where we are supposed to remove duplicate items from a list without using sets or the .contains() method. Basically just using iterators and the .equals() method. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class sample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws BadListException {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("A");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("C");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("D");


    unique(myList);
    System.out.println(myList);


}
public static List<String> unique( List<String> items ) throws BadListException { 

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> itr = items.listIterator();

    // If items is null, throw a BadListException. 

    if (items == null){
        throw new BadListException();
    }
    // If items is empty, return a new empty list. 

    if (items.isEmpty()){
        return newList;
    }

    // Otherwise create and return a new list that contains the items 
    // in L with all duplicates removed.  
    // Example: items: "A","B","C"              result: "A","B","C" 
    // Example: items: "A","A","A"              result: "A" 
    // Example: items: "A","B","B","C","A","D"  result: "A","B","C","D" 

    while (itr.hasNext()){
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size()-1; i++){
            if (itr.next().equals(items.get(i))){
                itr.remove();
            }
        }

    }
    items = newList;
    return newList;
```

If someone could please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I should go about doing it instead that would be very helpful. Please note that since this is to prepare me for a test I would appreciate an explanation rather than just the correct piece of code.

Comment: Excellent way of phrasing a "homework question"! Now can you tell us how/where things are going wrong or you?

Comment: you are returning the `newList` which you never change.

Comment: Well firstly the first item in the collection always gets erased (this I believe is because the first element being iterated will always equal itself, in order to avoid this I could start my for loop at index 1 instead of index 0 and that would fix the problem I belive) but more importantly when I add a duplicate item at any location other than right next to the item itself (eg. A, B, C, B) then the program continues running indefinitely. 

Just a clarification: the program does work as intended if I keep all duplicate items side by side and newList is returned without duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than explaining exactly what is going wrong, I'm going to suggest that you use a debugger to see what the program is currently doing.  In particular, look at what the iterator is returning each time you call `iter.next()`.

Hints for a correct solution:

1. You will need to use more than one iterator ...
2. You are not putting anything into the list you are returning.
3. You need to make up you mind whether you are creating and returning a new list, or removing elements from the existing one.  Doing BOTH doesn't make sense.

---

In future, when you ask a question, you should provide a better statement of what the program is actually supposed to do.  For instance:

- You don't say whether the `unique` method is supposed to remove elements from the argument list or return a new list containing (just) the unique elements.
- You don't say whether the order of the elements in the list(s) matters.
- You don't say whether it is OK to change the input list ... or not.

All of these things matter in deciding how to solve a problem like this.  Especially in the real world.  Even your assignment did not state these things, you still need to make up your own mind how your code is intended to work ... and document this with javadoc comments.

Answer (score 3):

- when `i==0` your `iterator.next()` and `get(i)` would be the same element, so you just removed it.
- for the same list, better not do `iterator.remove()` within a `for` loop.
- you didn't `add` anything to the `newList`, and returned it simply
- a suggestion for this assignment:

you could first **sort** the list, then go through it, if an element is equal to its previous one, remove the element. You could of course create a new list to hold those unique elements if you want.

my 2 cents

Comment: sorting the list will perturb the order of the list elements.  The problem is that the OP has not properly explained what the method is supposed to do ... and his existing code suffers from "multiple personality disorder".

Comment: @StephenC you are right. the order of e would be changed by sorting. Then the question/assignment must define, how to remove duplicates. e.g. "always keep the first/last/nth element, if dups found". otherwise the order could be "changed" as well. anyway if the Q is defined well, the solution is not hard to impl. well, keeping `nth`element might be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the solution :

```
    List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("1","4","8","1","4","5","1");
    Collections.sort(list);

    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
    String old = itr.next();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        String next = itr.next();

        if(old.equals(next))
        {
            itr.remove();
        }
        old = next;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a list and removing elements changes the list... If you looked at element "4" and decided to remove it, what is the next element you look at? Hint: it's not the original element "5" but the new element ”5”...

Answer (score 1):

You could just create your own iterator whose purpose is to only return a duplicated value once.

```
public class NoDuplicatesIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final List<T> array;
    private final List<T> encountered;
    private int index = 0;

    public NoDuplicatesIterator(List<T> array) {
        this.array = array;
        encountered = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (index > array.size() - 1) {
            return false;
        }

        while (encountered.contains(array.get(index)) && index < array.size() - 1) {
            index++;
        }

        return index <= array.size() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        encountered.add(array.get(index));
        return array.get(index++);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{100, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 15, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 99, 99, 100, 99, 2, 77, 23, 14, 2, 15});
        NoDuplicatesIterator<Integer> it = new NoDuplicatesIterator(array);

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
code extract without using iterator 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

  public class Test {
    final static List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Test(){

        str.add("A");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("A");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        System.out.println(str);


    }

    public  List<String> rmovedDuplicate(List<String> str){

        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i =0; i<str.size();i++){
            for (int j=i+1; j<str.size();j++){
                if(str.get(i).equals(str.get(j))){
                    str.remove(j);
                    i=0;

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("final list :"+str);
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.rmovedDuplicate(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: @kishor : Set's functionality is to remove duplicates. If you are using sets then there is no need to use list and convert to set u can directly use set. When you add your elements into set you will get non duplicate elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of doing it is as below.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Entered Main");
        Test();
        System.out.println(str);
        set.addAll(str);
        System.out.println(set);
        str.clear();
        str.addAll(set);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    final static List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    final static Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    public static void Test(){

        str.add("A");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("A");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        str.add("B");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("C");
        str.add("D");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Test method to populate the list is copied from Vidyarani Shinde's answer.

Comment: @Vidyarani: Yes but as he need the data in list so I just added it to list again.

Answer (score 0):

## very simple

`way is ..first to check the list has that value if so ,skip adding it if not add the element and u get your unique list...instead of running intensive Iterator operation :)`

`Example`

```
List<Integer> listOfUserIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     Integer UserIdCheck = 0;
     for (User userTest : userCollection) {
     UserIdCheck = userService.getUserByRegionCode(userTest.                      .getRegionId());
    if (!listOfUserIds.contains(UserIdCheck)) //check befor adding listOfUserIds.add(UserIdCheck);
        }
  } 
  return listOfUserIds.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""); // if u like can remove [ and ] from the list and simply return a string like "4,5,6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used both advanced for each and also tried by converting `ArrayList` to `HashSet` and again to `ArrayList`. Both of the solution works fine. You can choose any one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();

    wordDulicate.add("Tom");
    wordDulicate.add("Jones");
    wordDulicate.add("Sam");
    wordDulicate.add("Jamie");
    wordDulicate.add("Robie");
    wordDulicate.add("Helen");
    wordDulicate.add("Helen");
    wordDulicate.add("Helen");
    wordDulicate.add("Helen");
    wordDulicate.add("Tom");
    wordDulicate.add("Troy");
    wordDulicate.add("Mika");
    wordDulicate.add("Tom");

    System.out.println("Array List size"+wordDulicate.size());

    ArrayList<String> nonDuplicat=new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(wordDulicate));

    System.out.println("Array List size"+nonDuplicat.size());
    ArrayList<String> nonDuplicatThroughIterator=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String each:wordDulicate){
        if(!nonDuplicatThroughIterator.contains(each))
            nonDuplicatThroughIterator.add(each);
    }
    System.out.println("Array List size"+nonDuplicatThroughIterator.size());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume that `ArrayList` implements `ListADT`, that the `ArrayList` and `ArrayListIterator` classes are implemented as expected, and that `BadListException` is an unchecked exception with a zero-argument constructor. Assume also that null elements may not be added to a list.

I have to complete the Java method specified below, making use of iterators. My solution should meet these requirements:

1. must explicitly use iterators for traversing lists (i.e., you may not use a for-loop or Java's extended-for loop)
2. must not use the `contains` method
3. may use any `ListADT` methods (except `contains`) described in the [on-line reading,](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs367-1/) including `ListADT.iterator()`, but must not use any other `List` methods not mentioned there
4. must not modify the contents of the parameters.

The skeleton of the function:

```
public static ListADT<String> union(ListADT<String> list1, ListADT<String> list2) {
    // If list1 or list2 (or both list1 and list2) is null, throw a BadListException. 
    // If list1 and list2 are both empty, return a new empty list.
    // If list1 is empty (but not list2), return a new list containing the strings in
    //     list2 with all duplicates removed.
    // If list2 is empty (but not list1), return a new list containing the strings in
    //     list1 with all duplicates removed.
    // Otherwise, create and return a new list that contains the strings in list1 and
    //     the strings in list2 with all duplicates removed.
    //
    // Examples:
    //  list1: "a","b","c"          list2: "d","e","f"      result: "a","b","c","d","e","f"
    //  list1: "a","c","b","d"      list2: "e","d","a","f"  result: "a","c","b","d","e","f"
    //  list1: "a","b","c","b","a"  list2: "c","a","b"      result: "a","b","c"
    //
    // Note: the list returned does not need to be in any particular order
```

I have to make sure that my solution only uses the methods that are in the `ListADT` interface described in the on-line reading (including an iterator method, as mentioned above).

How can I do this?

Comment: You should definitely ask a new question.  You will not get an answer by posting your question as an answer to an old question.  I have edited your "answer", though, so that you can copy it and paste it into a reasonably formatted question.  Once you do that, you should delete this.